# Reactjs API Request Issue

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get some data from GameSpot API and display it.I can see the data in console but can't see it on my webpage.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


class Games extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          games: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://www.gamespot.com/api/games/?api_key=[APIKEY]&format=json&filter=name:Cyberpunk 2077,limit:10`)          
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    games: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
            })


    }
    render() {
        const {games} = this.state;
        console.log(games);

        return (
            <div>
              <p>{games.name}</p>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to see the resulted data on my webpage

**Edit:** *console.log* gives:

[image]

Comment: can you please show the consoled data?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxMdf.png

Comment: Ok, then I think you need to do something like this:  **<p>{games.results[0].name}</p>**

Comment: It didn't worked.I got this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mapping your elements wrongly.

Try this inside `render` function:

```
const {results} = this.state.games;
let names =[];
if(results && results.length) {
  results.forEach(result=> {
    names.push(<p>{result.name}</p>);
  });
}
return (
  <div>
    {names}
  </div>
);
```

Edit: I had to handle the situation when the state is null.

Hope it helps. Cheers!!

Comment: I'm getting this error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions" at this line <p>{result.name}</p>

Comment: I edited my answer a few times after answering first time. Did you try this last one?

Comment: I have tried the last one and I got this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Comment: Oh! I got it. Wait

Answer (score 0):

You need to [iterate over the object](https://hackernoon.com/5-techniques-to-iterate-over-javascript-object-entries-and-their-performance-6602dcb708a8) like,

```
Object.keys(games.name).forEach(function(key) {
    <p>{games.name[key]}</p>
});
```

Comment: How do you know if the data is an object?

Comment: @AdityaSrivast As the OP trying to access the data using `games.name`, I suppose we only use dot(.) operator for object.